conexión FTP con TLS Implícito en Python
Eh estado trabajando estos días en un proyecto el cual consiste en conectarme a un servidor Ftp utilizando Python para posteriormente listar , y obtener los archivos que se encuentran ahí listado, este es el código que estoy implementando .
import ftplib
import ssl
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class ImplicitFTP_TLS(ftplib.FTP_TLS):
    """FTP_TLS subclass that automatically wraps sockets in SSL to support implicit FTPS."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._sock = None
        self.context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
        self.context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE  # No verificar los certificados del servidor
        self.context.check_hostname = False  # No comprobar el nombre del host

    @property
    def sock(self):
        """Return the socket."""
        return self._sock

    @sock.setter
    def sock(self, value):
        """When modifying the socket, ensure that it is ssl wrapped."""
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, ssl.SSLSocket):
            value = self.context.wrap_socket(value, server_hostname=self.host)
        self._sock = value

def connect_ftp(server, user, password, port):
    try:
        ftp_client = ImplicitFTP_TLS()
        print(f"Conectando a {server}:{port} con TLS implícito...")
        ftp_client.connect(host=server, port=port)
        print("Conectado.")
        ftp_client.login(user=user, passwd=password)
        print("Autenticado.")
        ftp_client.prot_p()
        print("Protección de datos establecida.")
        ftp_client.set_pasv(True)
        return ftp_client
    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        print("Error FTP:", str(e))
        return None

def list_files(ftp_client):
    try:
        files = ftp_client.nlst()  # Utilizar ftp_client, no ftp
        print("Archivos en el directorio actual:")
        for file in files:
            print(file)
        return files
    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        print("Error de FTP:", str(e))
        return []

def print_working_directory(ftp_client):
    try:
        cwd = ftp_client.pwd()
        print(f"Directorio actual: {cwd}")
        return cwd
    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        print("Error al obtener el directorio actual:", str(e))
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ftp_server = "ftp.sitio.com.co"
    ftp_user = "mdeica"
    ftp_pass = "Nus20*"
    ftp_port = 990

    ftp_client = connect_ftp(ftp_server, ftp_user, ftp_pass, ftp_port)
    if ftp_client:
        current_directory = print_working_directory(ftp_client)
        print(f"Te encuentras en el directorio: {current_directory}")
        list_files(ftp_client)  # Intenta listar los archivos

Pero al momento de ejecutarlo me realiza correctamente la conexion pero cuando realizo el proceso de listar me arroja un mensaje de error de
Conectado.
Autenticado.
Protección de datos establecida.
Directorio actual: /
Te encuentras en el directorio: /
Error de FTP: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)

El cual no he podido solucionar, alguno ha tenido el mismo problema .? algunas recomendación  u opiniones.
Gracias
he intentado modificar la class donde defino el certificado SSL pero no logro obtener el cometido.
class ImplicitFTP_TLS(ftplib.FTP_TLS):
    """FTP_TLS subclass that automatically wraps sockets in SSL to support implicit FTPS."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._sock = None
        self.context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
        self.context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE  # No verificar los certificados del servidor
        self.context.check_hostname = False  # No comprobar el nombre del host

    @property
    def sock(self):
        """Return the socket."""
        return self._sock

    @sock.setter
    def sock(self, value):
        """When modifying the socket, ensure that it is ssl wrapped."""
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, ssl.SSLSocket):
            value = self.context.wrap_socket(value, server_hostname=self.host)
        self._sock = value

